# Helpme understand what is happening with this ios crash

Tags: ios, cordova, crash, testflight

My app is a phonegap app, I'm using phonegap 2.9 with several plugins.
I have no idea whats going on!

If you need more info please just ask.

```
Incident Identifier: ...
CrashReporter Key:   ...
Hardware Model:      iPod5,1
Process:             ... [2051]
Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/...
Identifier:          ...
Version:             8 (1.0.0)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-01-27 16:23:37.879 -0300
OS Version:          iOS 7.0.4 (11B554a)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x2ee2f7ae CFRelease + 902
1   CoreFoundation                  0x2ee371dc -[__NSArrayI dealloc] + 60
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3921eb06 objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 170
3   Foundation                      0x2f8d9536 __delayedPerformCleanup + 46
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2ee3714e CFRunLoopTimerInvalidate + 434
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2eec9d2c __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 836
6   CoreFoundation                  0x2eec808e __CFRunLoopRun + 1206
7   CoreFoundation                  0x2ee32c22 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
8   CoreFoundation                  0x2ee32a06 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
9   GraphicsServices                0x33b2227e GSEventRunModal + 134
10  UIKit                           0x316d6044 UIApplicationMain + 1132
11  ....                        0x000f315e main (main.m:32)
12  libdyld.dylib                   0x3971bab4 start + 0
```

This is the information of the crash that testflight gives me

```
#   Binary Image Name   Address Symbol
0   IamatClientWeb  0x0015ae70  testflight_backtrace
1   IamatClientWeb  0x0015a758  TFSignalHandler
2   libsystem_platform.dylib    0x39836062  _sigtramp
3   ... 0x00105118  -[CSLabel dealloc] in CSLabel.m on Line 113
4   libobjc.A.dylib 0x3921eb0a  _ZN11objc_object17sidetable_releaseEb
5   CoreFoundation  0x2ee2f654  CFRelease
6   CoreFoundation  0x2ee3ba22  -[__NSDictionaryM dealloc]
7   libobjc.A.dylib 0x3921eb0a  _ZN11objc_object17sidetable_releaseEb
8   ... 0x001061ec  -[CSMeasurement dealloc] in CSMeasurement.m on Line 199
9   libobjc.A.dylib 0x3921eb0a  _ZN11objc_object17sidetable_releaseEb
10  ... 0x000f98f0  -[CSRequest dealloc] in CSRequest.m on Line 197
11  libobjc.A.dylib 0x3921eb0a  _ZN11objc_object17sidetable_releaseEb
12  libsystem_blocks.dylib  0x39738ac4  _Block_release
13  libdispatch.dylib   0x396fd272  _dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$mp
14  libdispatch.dylib   0x396fd06a  _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp
15  libdispatch.dylib   0x396fdce0  _dispatch_root_queue_drain
16  libdispatch.dylib   0x396fdf58  _dispatch_worker_thread2
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x39838dbe  _pthread_wqthread
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x39838c83
```

I cant find CSLabel.m or CSMeasurement.m  in my code

Comment: The crash happens occasionally

Comment: Do you have any log output or any way to reproduce the crash? Or are you just getting this crash report from users out in the field?

Comment: I installed my app via testflight and it crashed as soon as I started it. After that no crash.